# How accept yes/no dialog in cli?

Tags: bash

i want to auto accept agreement dialog - when installing android-sdk components in docker.

This is the part of my dockerfile - this section should install additional packages for android-sdk, but it does not work.

```
RUN echo y | ${ANDROID_HOME}/tools/android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter "${ANDROID_SDK_COMPONENTS}"
```

Please advice - how i can accept agreement by default.
Thank you

Comment: You look close, just get rid of `RUN` before `echo y`, or if `RUN` is required then `echo y | RUN ${ANDROID_HOME}/......`

Answer (score 1):

Try `yes` command :

```
yes | ${ANDROID_HOME}/tools/android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter "${ANDROID_SDK_COMPONENTS}"
```

**Update :**

It should work if you add a timeout before echoing `y` :

```
while true; do echo "y"; sleep 1;done | ${ANDROID_HOME}/tools/android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter "${ANDROID_SDK_COMPONENTS}"
```

Comment: nope - this optiond oes not work - i try ```yes ``` already

```Max number of retries exceeded. Rejecting 'android-sdk-license-ed0d0a5b'
```

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: while true; do echo "y"; sleep 1;done... worked for me.